# Prevent image overlap

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to have 3 images next to each other, not overlapping. This is what I've tried, to no avail:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 0.5em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 0.5em;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.source,
.data {
  width: 100%;
}

.data .camera {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="title">

    <h1>My Webpage</h1>
    <h2>It's Totally Awesome</h2>

  </div>
  <div id="content">

    <div class="source" id="cameraFeeds">

      <h3>Camera Feeds</h3>
      <div class="data">
        <div class="camera" id="camera1">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x240">
          <h4>Camera 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="camera" id="camera2">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x240">
          <h4>Camera 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="camera" id="camera3">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x240">
          <h4>Camera 3</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The images either overlap each other or one goes below the other two.

This is the layout I'm looking for:

[image: Ideal Layout]

So, each image has the same vertical position and all 3 are next to each other, without any overlap. Ideally, the size should scale based on the width of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```